# Member Function checking: Implement compilation-time checkings with C++11 features

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-concepts

I have read that C++11 has sufficient static checking (compile time) so as to implement a big part of what should have been Concepts checking of C++11(removed). *(I've read this in the comments of a recent question about Concepts removed... - that question was fastly closed as not constructive).*

The C++03 code below only check the presence of a member function in a class (on which my template class wants to work). Here are 4 member functions that are searched for, and I always use the same pattern:

- a typedef to define a typedef of the prototype of the function
- a call to static_cast that breaks compilation if ever the typename TExtension doesn't define such a member function, or if it has different prototype

Here is the code:

```
template <typename TExtension>
class
{
...
    void checkTemplateConcept()
    {
        typedef unsigned long (TExtension::*memberfunctionRequestedId)();
        static_cast<memberfunctionRequestedId>(&TExtension::getRequestId);

        typedef eDirection (TExtension::*memberfunctionDirection)();
        static_cast<memberfunctionDirection>(&TExtension::getDirection);

        typedef eDriveWay (TExtension::*memberfunctionDriveWay)();
        static_cast<memberfunctionDriveWay>(&TExtension::getDriveWay);

        typedef unsigned long (TExtension::*memberfunctionCycleId)();
        static_cast<memberfunctionCycleId>(&TExtension::getCycleId);
    }
}
```

This was in some part of my code, but it was completely based on **C++03**. I would rewrite it gladly, with those **new C++11 features**... what should be used here instead ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C++11, you could make the compiler to print the good error messages with `static_assert` as:

```
typedef unsigned long (TExtension::*required_type)();
typedef decltype(&TExtension::getRequestId) actual_type;

static_assert(std::is_same<required_type, actual_type>::value,
     "The type of getRequestId must be unsigned long (C::*)()");
```

Now if the type of member function doesn't match, the compiler will print this helpful message:

```
"The type of getRequestId must be unsigned long (C::*)()"
```

You could make it more descriptive if you want to. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes in C++11, SFINAE was extended to expressions, so you can define a trait like `is_t_extension` to detect for the presences of the member functions, like this:

```
template<class... T>
struct holder
{
    typedef void type;
};

template<class T, class=void>
struct is_t_extension
: std::false_type
{};

template<class T, class=void>
struct is_t_extension<T, typename holder<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().getRequestId),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().getDirection),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().getDriveWay),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().getCycleId)
>::type>
: std::true_type
{};
```

Now this just checks for their presence. With some work you could extend the above to detect valid signatures, or you could use the [Tick](https://github.com/pfultz2/Tick) library to write the trait instead, which looks a lot cleaner:

```
TICK_TRAIT(is_t_extenstion)
{
    template<class T>
    auto requires_(T&& x) -> TICK_VALID(
        returns<unsigned long>(x.getRequestId),
        returns<eDirection>(x.getDirection),
        returns<eDriveWay>(x.getDriveWay),
        returns<unsigned long>(x.getCycleId)
    );
};
```

Then in your class you could just use a `static_assert` to report the error:

```
template <typename TExtension>
class foo
{
    static_assert(is_t_extension<TExtension>(), "Not a TExtension");
};
```

Or if you want to allow for specializations, you can use `TICK_CLASS_REQUIRES`:

```
template <typename TExtension, class=void>
class foo;

template <typename TExtension>
class foo<TExtension, TICK_CLASS_REQUIRES(is_t_extension<TExtension>())>
{
    ...
};
```